# Facebook - finding users by name

Tags: facebook

I'm very new to facebook and wanted to know if this is even possible to do with facebook API.

If a user searches for a name on my website - say "Jamie Smith" - I want to pass this name to facebook and find all users that match that name - so if I can get back their photo and name to display on my site - so users can identify the right person.

I'm using PHP so if there's any example or link that you can provide will be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Facebook is all about "friends", not about pulling information on random people. You could easily get a list of the user's friends with a name of Jamie, Smith, or Jamie Smith. Facebook isn't really designed around arbitrary name searches (privacy issues).

Comment: hmm I see - I read on some forums that people were able to run such queries and they were complaining that they suddenly stopped returning results. I guess as part of an update - facebook made that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) to do this. Specifically, you can query the `user` table on `name`. Of course, you will only be able to see the public data for those users.

Comment: tlofin - I tried this but it looks like uid is required for searching on the user table. Like if I search select name,pic from user where name = 'Jamie Smith' - I'm not getting back anything - but only if I provide uid - I'm getting results. In my case - I dont have uid's - all I have is a name - Thanks

Comment: @Gublooo, could you post the specific query you tried? This should be possible.

Comment: This is my code - $fb = new Facebook('xyz', 'abc');
$q = "SELECT name,pic FROM user WHERE name = 'Jamie'";
$query = $fb->api_client->fql_query($q);

Comment: Sorry, it looks like Facebook coincidentally just made a major update or something, so I'm not sure exactly how this works now. I think you can use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) for this now.

Answer (score 0):

If I right, you can find only your friend by name (FQL):

```
fql?q=SELECT uid, name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strpos(lower(name), 'john') >= 0
```

By you can try find by Graph API:

```
search?q=mark&20zuckerberg&type=user
```